# sendEmail failure

Tags: bugs, sendemail, perl

I want to send a email. Here my working example on ubuntu:

```
sendEmail -f <FROM_EMAIL> -t <TO_EMAIL> -u 'Book' -m 'ISBN: 12345-678-90' -s smtp.gmail.com -o message-charset=utf8 -o tls=yes -xu <USERNAME> -xp <PASSWORD>
```

On the raspberry i get an error:

```
invalid SSL_version specified at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 332
```

I have no idea, what ist wrong. Has anyone an idea, how to solve the problem? Alternarive - an replacement for the sendEmail without own smtp server?

Comment: What distro are you using and is it up to date?

Comment: I'm using the raspbian wheezy and yes - it is up to date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

...it seems to be a bug in Debian:

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=679911

and here replacement for sendEmail:

http://www.logix.cz/michal/devel/smtp-cli

Now i can send email with this command:

```
smtp-cli --verbose --host smtp.gmail.com --user <USER> --auth-plain --from <FROM_EMAIL> --to <TO_EMAIL> --pass <PASSWORD> --subject "Test" --body-plain "Log files are attached."

smtp-cli --verbose --host smtp.gmail.com --user abcde --auth-plain --from abcde@gmail.com --to fggga@gmail.com --pass topSecret --subject "Test" --body-plain "Log files are attached."
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. I should note that I had this problem on an x64 ubuntu 15.04, so it looks like nobody is going to fix the Perl bug ...

Answer (score 7):

The bug appears to be in line 1490 of /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/IO/Socket/SSL.pm.

The SSL_version is being coded as "SSLv3 TLSv1" and the regular expression is failing.

I hacked it as a workaround as follows...

change:

```
    m{^(!?)(?:(SSL(?:v2|v3|v23|v2/3))|(TLSv1[12]?))$}i
```

to:

```
    m{^(!?)(?:(SSL(?:v2|v3|v23|v2/3))|(TLSv1[12]?))}i
```

That did the trick for me.

Comment: nice, i must try it :)

Comment: works, but i've used the /usr/share/perl5/IO/Socket/SSL.pm. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 4):

After installing `sendemail` on Raspberry pi, there will be an error

> "No TLS support!".

To fix it, install tls packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libnet-ssleay-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install libio-socket-ssl-perl libnet-ssleay-perl
```

Then after running "sendemail", we will get the error

> "invalid SSL_version specified at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 332"

Method below works:

```
sudo nano usr/share/perl5/IO/Socket/SSL.pm
```

then change

- `m{^(!?)(?:(SSL(?:v2|v3|v23|v2/3))|(TLSv1[12]?))$}i`

to:

- `m{^(!?)(?:(SSL(?:v2|v3|v23|v2/3))|(TLSv1[12]?))}i`

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for SSL failure is the time used for time stamping the communications. Make sure that the system time on the Pi is current.

Either run `ntpd` or run `sudo ntpdate <some time server>`. `ntpd` corrects the system time in small increments. if your time is off by hours, it will take days to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Tom & Marius !

I've found that you have to travel to,

```
sudo nano usr/share/perl5/IO/Socket/SSL.pm
```

and replace this:

```
m{^(!?)(?:(SSL(?:v2|v3|v23|v2/3))|(TLSv1[12]?))$}i
```

with this:

```
m{^(!?)(?:(SSL(?:v2|v3|v23|v2/3))|(TLSv1[12]?))}i
```

This solves it. :-)